# Как отправить сообщение в ВК с помощью POST запросов, избегая api

Tags: python, post, вконтакте

Нашел код для авторизации, он вроде работает:

```
import lxml.html
import requests

login = 'логин'
password = 'пароль'
url = 'https://vk.com/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language':'ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'DNT':'1'
}
session = requests.session()
data = session.get(url, headers=headers).content
page = lxml.html.fromstring(data)

form = page.forms[0]
form.fields['email'] = login
form.fields['pass'] = password

response = session.post(form.action, data=form.form_values())
print(response.text)
```

Помогите разобраться, как в будущем самому смотреть какие post запросы куда с сайта отправляются, и как их отловить, чтобы потом перенести в python.

P.S.
Сделал, как говорил пользователь `Mr Morgan` и получил такие вот значения

```
act:a_send
al:1
gid:0
guid:151773532908381
hash:1517735163_cd46fbd56673503461
im_v:2
media:
msg: test message
random_id:626404632
to: id того, кому я писал
```

Дальше Mr Morgan писал

> Вы увидите значения переменных, их нужно указывать в качестве словаря(аналогично headers), но передавать в качестве data.

Но переменные `guid`, `hash` и `random_id` постоянно меняются, как их формировать?

Answer (score 2):

Вот готовый код.

```
import lxml.html
import requests

login = ваш Логин
password = ваш пароль

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language':'ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'DNT':'1'}

def log_in(url, headers, session, login, password, proxy = None):
    data = session.get(url, headers=headers, proxies = proxy)
    page = lxml.html.fromstring(data.content)

    form = page.forms[0]
    form.fields['email'] = login
    form.fields['pass'] = password

    response = session.post(form.action, data=form.form_values())

def send_msg(msg, whom, headers, session, proxy=None):
    data_msg=f'act=a_send&al=1&entrypoint=&gid=0&hash={user_hash}&im_v=3&media=&msg={msg}&to={whom}'
    session.post('https://vk.com/al_im.php', data=data_msg)


session = requests.session()
log_in('https://vk.com/', headers, session, login, password)
send_msg(msg, whom, user_hash, headers, session)
```

Функция send_msg - собственно отправка сообщения, ее аргументы:

```
1. msg--сообщение, которое вы хотите отправить
2. whom - id пользователя, которому вы отправляете
3. user_hash - это hash в post запросе, его достаточно один раз для одного пользователя взять (как это сделать уже сказано Mr Morgan
```

Answer (score -1):

**Google Chrome**

`F12` -> Вкладка `Network` ->
делаете так, чтобы браузер отправил форму(нажимаете кнопку `войти` или подобные) ->
нажимаете красную кнопку(stop record) -> просматриваете запросы, которые Вы поймали.

В остальных браузерах нужно найти панель разработчика и сделать аналогичные действия.

---

Вы увидите значения переменных, их нужно указывать в качестве словаря(аналогично headers), но передавать в качестве data.

```
session.post(..., data={...})
```

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, получил набор переменных. Среди них есть три, которые постоянно меняются: `guid`, `hash` и `random_id`. Подскажите как их генерировать.

Comment: Это зависит от сайта.

Comment: поясните пожалуйста. В каком смысле, "это зависит от сайта"? Мне нужен только ВК.

Comment: Тогда смотрите по аналогии с https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/vk_api/audio.py

Comment: ваш пример не уместен, там ни слова про то, о чем я спрашивал. Цитата: "Среди них есть три, которые постоянно меняются: `guid`, `hash` и `random_id`. Подскажите как их генерировать. "

Comment: random_id - рандомное число, которое Вам хочется(рандомный id сообщения)
Остальные можно найти, отлаживая код js в том же меню.
(sources ->network -> top -> vk.com -> js -> cmodules/web ->imn.js -> ctrl+f a_send -> читаете js код, понимаете что он делает и вуаля.
А вообще для имитации браузера можно использовать selenium или webbrowser